# Linking Error, Makefile on kernel module

Tags: makefile, module, kernel

This is my **Makefile**.

```
obj-m := my-mod.o 
my-mod-objs := my-mod-interrupt.o my-mod-control.o my-mod-fops.o

all:    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules 

clean:  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

In the file **my-mod-fops.c** I have:

```
extern void *pcpu_dev;
```

In the file **my-mod.c** the definition of the variable.

```
void *pcpu_dev;
```

So, when launching make command I obtain the following warning:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build M=/home/userx/debian/Coding/Module modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "pcpu_dev" [/home/userx/debian/Coding/Module/my-mod.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
```

I think this is a linking problem, but I do not know how to fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: is it 1 or 2 underscores?

Comment: Just one, I made the error while typing the question.

Comment: Could you check if it throws the same error if you just delete the `extern` keyword from `my-mod-fops.c` and put it into `my-mod.c`?

Comment: This works! So, do we know why it behaves this way?

Comment: Great! Yes, it has to do with the order in which the linker resolves symbols. It does it from left to right in the command line: if you check the actual compilation command you will see that `my-mod.o` goes first. There are some workarounds for this in case you want to keep it like before.

Comment: That makes sense! So can you put some reference where I can look for workaround?

Comment: well, I have never tried it with kernel module compilations, but sending `-Wl,--start-group` to gcc should do

Comment: Use `ccflags-y` in the Makefile (check '3.7 Compilation flags' [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt))

Comment: Is `my-mod.c` **ever compiled** with given Makefile? This file would be compiled if you omit `my-mod-objs` assignment (by default, Kbuild search source file with the same name as the module). But if you assign `my-mod-objs`, then Kbuild builds only those objects which are listed in this variable. And, as far as I remember, you cannot specify `my-mod.o` in that list (Kbuild limitation).

Comment: @user2443396 Did this work finally?

Comment: I solved in the following way:
`obj-m := my-mod-x.o`
`my-mod-x-objs := my-mod-interrupt.o my-mod-control.o my-mod-fops.o  my-mod-o`
I changed the name of the build module such that the module name and some file.o didn't match.